# C# protected memory error slowly killing my brain

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Getting the following error in Visual Studio 2017 using a Windows form on Windows 7. This happens on multiple computers. I have a set of editboxes within labels all set to hide or go visible when selecting a "form" in a combobox. What happens is I import text into these editboxes, wheel scroll or up/down arrows through the form combobox selecting the different labels to display or hide, when doing this eventually the editbox in one of these forms goes blank. When you go to type in the editbox you get the memory error. I've searched and searched for a solution with no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
    System.AccessViolationException occurred
    HResult=0x80004003
    Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
    Source=System.Windows.Forms
    StackTrace:
    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop        (IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
    at Notes.Program.Main() in documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Notes\Notes\Program.cs:line 19
```

The code for the import of the editbox that goes blank.

```
List<string> ort = imp.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
//Name regex match
var match = new Regex(@"((?<=: ).*(?=\[))");
var name = match.Match(ort[0]);
if (tChoice == 0) { user.Text = String.Empty; user.AppendText(name.Groups[0].ToString()); }
if (tChoice == 1) { pwuser.Text = String.Empty; pwuser.AppendText(name.Groups[0].ToString()); }
if (tChoice == 2)
{
    gmmuser.Text = String.Empty; requser.Text = String.Empty; reqAuser.Text = String.Empty; billuser.Text = String.Empty;
    gmmuser.AppendText(name.Groups[0].ToString()); requser.AppendText(name.Groups[0].ToString()); reqAuser.AppendText(name.Groups[0].ToString()); billuser.AppendText(name.Groups[0].ToString());
}
if (tChoice == 3) { emailuser.Text = String.Empty; emailuser.AppendText(name.Groups[0].ToString()); }
```

Comment: Can we see some code?  Can you provide a minimal example reproducing the issue?  Let's also start by looking at your mouse wheel and up down event handlers.

Comment: I don't have anything setup with the mouse wheel as far as handlers go. I'm not even sure which part of the code is causing this. It seems like a generic error and I don't know where to pinpoint the exact cause.

Comment: Are you making any p/invoke calls?  Start removing things from your application until the problem disappears.  Then you've narrowed it down at least.  Then... show us code.

Comment: 'This happens on multiple computers' ? do you mean you have tried this on other machines using in dev enviornment VS 2017 and windows. Or do you mean other machines requesting from a server?

Comment: I've taken the debugged version of the exe and ran it on another PC. You'll have to excuse my ignorance what is a p/invoke call?

Comment: start taking code out of the app (in big chunks) until it starts working, then start adding it back.

Comment: almost certainly it is not the code you show, you did something fancy / wrong earlier on and have trashed a stack or heap somewhere

Comment: Is `DllImport` used anywhere in your project?

Comment: Your code looks fine but it is not the way I would have done this. Just a thought, are you sure that the strings you are append actually contain data. If you append an empty string you get an empty string. Maybe your regex is missing a match.

Comment: Is there a way to debug and determine how I messed up the stack/heap?

Comment: @DasGoat try some of the suggestions above.  Start removing big chunks of code until the problem goes away - this will tell you where the problem is.  Then, show us that code!  Help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like it might have something to do with the target framework. I had it set to 4.6.2. I set it to 4.5.2 and have yet to come across the issue, fingers crossed.